# Rails - Find with no associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, include, find, associated-object

I want to select one user and add to it associated records such as child for this example. 
But only the child with a specific place_id.

This code works, but when the user doesn't have any child entry I got an error.

```
  @user = User.includes(:child).find(params[:id],
                                             :conditions => ["child.place_id = ?", @place_id])
```

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=19 [WHERE (child.place_id = 0)]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try `where` clause, since you are already using brute SQL. This will not produce error and will either fetch or set to nil:

```
@user = User.includes(:child).
             where("users.id=? AND child.place_id = ?", 
                    params[:id],@place_id).first
```

PS: Is it `child.place_id` or `children.place_id`? ActiveRecord tends to pluralize table names.

**EDIT:**

This only works if there are children. If you want it to work event without children,do this:

```
@user = User.joins('LEFT JOIN child on child.user_id = users.id').
             where('child.place_id = ? AND users.id = ?', @place_id, params[:id]).
             select('users.field1, child.field2 as field3')
```

If you want specific fields, add them in select method above, which is provided as an example.

Comment: I already tried your solution :) but instead of the error I got "null", not even the user information. It's "child" it's just for the example. Thanks for you help btw

Comment: In that case, if you have a hands-on-example, I would appreciate seeing it in order to be able to provide valid feedback.

Comment: I don't really have any other example to provide :/ I'm stuck. I tried so many query, but still the same issue...

Comment: With your second query I get all the users, I want to be able to select only one specific user. Same as your first query.

Comment: that returns me a list of the same user.

Comment: my model is very simple, according to your query you exactly understood my problem. It's just that the query is not right. I have a parent table and a child table, the child table has a field parent_id and age. I want the parent with the id=5 including only his children with the age = 15 for example. Thanks for you help. So I only want to get the user with the id = 15, including his child if exist.

Comment: Wait.. if it is so, then what do you mean "returns you a list"? This query should do exactly what you are describing... A user with all his children, each row containing the user and the child. Then, it will filter out only the child with place_id you provide... If it's more than one, it will be more than one rows...

Comment: That returns me a list of the same user for example user with id 43 [{id: 43, child : {}}, {id: 43, child: {}}, ... ]